# Minimum PSU requirement for my build

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, computer-building

I am trying to build a new system. Here is my summary

Processor : [i5-4690](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JST2QEW)

Motherboard : [ASRock H97M Pro4](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157512&cm_re=asrock_h97m_pro4-_-13-157-512-_-Product)

RAM : [G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3 1600](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231314&cm_re=gskill_8gb-_-20-231-314-_-Product)

GPU : [ASUS GeForce GTX 750 Ti OC-2GD5 2GB GDDR5 DirectX 11](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814121855&cm_re=Asus_GeForce_GTX_750_Ti_2GB-_-14-121-855-_-Product)

Internal Hard drive : [WD Blue WD10EZEX 1 TB](http://www.flipkart.com/wd-blue-wd10ezex-1-tb-internal-hard-drive/p/itmdhgybefghqrtq?pid=IHDDHGYBEFGHQRTQ&ref=L%3A9173044301570721236&srno=p_1&query=wd+1tb+internal&otracker=from-search)

PSU : [Seasonic S12II 430 Watts](http://www.flipkart.com/seasonic-s12ii-430-watts-psu/p/itmd5xz5bzevdbzp?pid=PSUD5XZ4PQNBPMES&ref=L%3A5728131163440564620&srno=p_8&query=psu&otracker=from-search)

After extensive search i have found that PSU is very important component should not compromise on it.

I have few question's here

1. What is the minimum PSU requirement for my build. Is 430W is good enough for me?
2. Is there any bottle neck in my build

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser! Questions about shopping, "good/better alternatives" are not welcome here. We share knowledge about facts, not opinions here. Please edit your post and remove questions that may require opinion based answer :)

Comment: @Kamil - removed those two questions

Comment: His question is not an opinion or asking for opinion based things. He is just asking what the minimum requirement for his wattage.

Comment: @cloudnyn3 There were 2 extra questions ("Is my GPU a good choice or Do i have any other better alternatives in this price range 100$ - 150$" and "Is there any good alternative in any of my component". He edited his post. Maybe I overreacted, but I wrote my first comment to save him from ban, because some people don't care about new users and just downvote shopping questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need a power supply with at least 35 Amps on the 12V rail. Anything under that would be cutting it too close, because the 750Ti alone requires more than 20A and yours is an overclocked edition.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2061335/300w-18a-run-gtx-750.html

Comment: So what you are mean to say is my PSU is not enough for my GPU I didn't understood can you elaborate. In the site it is mentioned that required power supply is 150 W.

Comment: Wattage is not the only thing that matters, you also have to look at detailed specs. http://www.seasonicusa.com/images/S12II/PowerDistribution.jpg Here's the relevant information for that particular power supply. It is probably enough but you might want to go with something slightly more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular build I would recommend a 500 to 650 watt power supply unit. That should easily suffice for that particular application. The only bottlenecks in your system that I see are your video card and your hard drive. Solid state drives are leaps and bounds beyond that of a hard drive. The read and write speed of a solid state drive can be hundreds of times greater than that of a hard disk drive. The video card will work, but I would spend a little extra on a 760 series.